# All responses via single point of exit

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm looking for guidance from experienced Lumen/Laravel developers towards the following challenge: I want all responses to go thru a single class/method.

I'm coding a small API using Lumen and there's no problem in returning JSON, however I do not want to have `return response()->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA']);` in every method which returns.

What if later there's a business case where I need to add `token => 'secret'` to absolutely all end-points? Hence I'd like to have a single point of exit and wondering what is the best to achieve this.

Middleware? Is it possible to intercept everything just before it is being returned? I know we have terminable Middleware, however that's being run after the response has been sent to the browser.

Am I looking at the option to writing my own helper or are there core Lumen/Laravel feature supporting this need?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel supports response macros, these allow you to modify your responses in any way you wish.

You can find the documentation for this here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#response-macros

This essentially allows you to modify any response that calls the macro, in pretty much any way you choose.

So if you wanted to add a token to your requests you could do

```
public function boot()
{
    Response::macro('myresponse', function ($value) {
        $token = getTokenFromSomwehere();
        return Response::make([
            'token' => $token,
            'user' => $value['user'],
             etc...
        ]);
    });
}
```

then when returning a response in your app use `return response()->myresponse($values)`